# SU Tag merge request [wi-fi] to [wireless-networking]

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms, tag-synonym-request

[wi-fi](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wi-fi) (60) --> [wireless-networking](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wireless-networking) (2507)

Comment: there's [tag:wifi] mapped as synomym, yet people have gone in for tagging as [tag:wi-fi]. Ayayay.

Comment: @Nifle : Sigh, Wimax and bluetooth pan isn’t wi fi.

Comment: @user2284570 - Nobody claims it is, but wi-fi is wireless-networking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
updating post history, 70 rows affected
updating posts, 63 rows affected
updating PostTags associations, 36 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 1 rows affected
updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [wireless-networking] and [wi-fi] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
2 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
Tag Synonym wi-fi -> wireless-networking was approved!
```

Done!